# Delphi Record audio and save to stream

Tags: android, delphi, audio, stream, indy

I am struggling to streaming audio on android. I can stream video using the `TCameraComponent` and Indy 10, now I'd like to add audio too.

If I use `TAudioCaptureDevice` to record the audio, how can I get the stream to send to the client?

The `TAudioCaptureDevice` class different from the `TCameraComponent` does not have an event when the buffer is ready, so I can not get the stream.

I've seen a lot of good components as wave audio, but unfortunately it just support Win32 and iOS, however I need to run on Android.

Is there a way to get the stream out of the `TAudioCaptureDevice`, to send to client? If not, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: `TAudioCaptureDevice` only supports capturing audio to a file, it cannot be streamed live. You might have to create your own `TCaptureDevice` implementation to do live audio streaming. Or just forget using FireMonkey for it and just access Android's audio APIs directly via JNI.

Comment: Or *maybe* you can open a file for writing with read sharing enabled, and have `TAudioCaptureDevice` write to that file, then have another thread that reads from the same file and streams it as needed.

Comment: How can i achieve that exactly? The TAudioCaptureDevice has the property FileName, where I give the path of the file and the format. I would have to start the recover, stop, then read the file with the thread to stream it? Then start the recover again.

Comment: No, the thread would open the same file in a read-only mode and read from it *while* it is being recorded. But that assumes the recording allows read-only access, which I do not know. Internally, `TAudioCaptureDevice` uses Android's [`MediaRecorder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) class, which does not support live streaming, and there is no information about what read/write mode it actually uses on the recorded file...

Comment: ... You might need to skip `TAudioCaptureDevice` altogether and use `MediaRecorder` directly, just so you can provide your own `FileDescriptor` that has two file streams attached to it - one for writing and one for reading.  Otherwise, find another third-party audio recording library for Android that supports live streaming.

Comment: Or, use Android's [`AudioRecord`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class, which allows you to poll audio data yourself, which you can then transmit as needed.